# Marshaller in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to marshal java objects to xml in spring integration. i've tried to use new MarshallingTransformer. but i don't know how to pass the marshaller into it.
This is my code:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
                            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                                   
                            )
                    )
                
                    .transform(xmlToObjectTransformer)
                    .convert(Customer.class)
                    .transform(new MarshallingTransformer("the marshaller should come here"))

                    .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.
You probably need to learn what are those marshallers and how to configure them: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#oxm.

Then you just need to have a bean for respective `Marshaller` and inject it into that `MarshallingTransformer` ctor.